# Dynamically render react component based on parent state

Tags: reactjs

My parent component, basically a form, has a child, an overlay with a loader, which only has to be displayed based on parent's state.

```
import React from 'react';
import Overlay from './overlay';

export default class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor {
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    this.state.loading = true;
    ...
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}>
     ...
     <Overlay />
    </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

I tried `React.cloneElement(<Overlay />, {})` but I don't know how to re-append this child to the parent and as I understand, it's not the React-way of doing things...

I also tried setting a `prop` ob `Overlay` based on `state` of the parent, like `React.cloneElement(<Overlay />, { visible = this.state.loading })` but cannot seem to get it to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of ternary operator to render you component. React JSX supports If-else logic for rendering like `{(this.state.loading == false) ? <Overlay /> : null}`

You should use `this.setState({loading: true});` to change state instead of a direct assignment. Also use `event.preventDefault()` in your `handleSubmit();`

```
import React from 'react';
import Overlay from './overlay';

export default class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor {
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
  }
  handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({loading: true});
    ...
  }

  render(){
    <form onSubmit {()=>{this.handleSubmit()}>

     {(this.state.loading == false) ? <Overlay /> : null}
    </form>
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. I tried `{(this.state.loading == true) ? <Overlay /> : null}` and `{(this.state.loading) ? <Overlay /> : null}` and `{this.state.loading && <Overlay />}`

Comment: use event.preventDefault in your handleSubmit. Check the updated answer

Comment: I already had this in my original code; omitted in question (thought it was irrelevant?)

Comment: `this.setState()` instead of directly assigning `this.state` was the clue. I would love to understand why...

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a good explanation on why you should use this.setState instead of this.state http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs

Comment: And yeah Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer the expression below than a ternary operator for the case in question

```
render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      { this.state.loading == false && <Overlay /> }
    </form>
  );
}
```

Remember not to miss a *return* clause in the render function. Remember not to change state by assignment directly. Here is a working component that submits the form by clicking a button, and displays a loading message. This is a typical React way to achieve the behavior.

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      loading: false
     };
  }
  handleSubmit() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        { this.state.loading && <div>loading...</div> }
        <button>click</button>
       </form>
     );
  }
}
```

---

Appendix - Below are two shorthand tricks.

**Ternary operator:**

Shorthand

```
render() {
  return condition === someCondition ? <CompA /> : <CompB />;
}
```

Longhand

```
render() {
  if ( condition === someCondition ) {
    return <CompA />;
  } else {
    return <CompB />;
  }
}
```

**Boolean AND operator &&:**

Shorthand

```
render() {
  return condition === someCondition && <CompA />;
}
```

Longhand

```
render() {
  if ( condition === someCondition ) {
    return <CompA />;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried `this.state.loading && <Overlay />` but nothing happened...

Comment: Did you bind the handle in the constructor? `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind( this );`

Comment: I edited the question: my submit handler is done like this `onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}`

Comment: Okay, then. Has the render function contained a `return` clause already?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't mention it at once. I updated the question.