# difference between setState and this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering what the difference is, if any, between using `this.setState({property: 1}) and`this.state.property = 1`

```
var App = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function(){
      return({number: 0})
   },

   increaseNumber: function(){
      this.state.number += 1;
   },

   decreaseNumber: function(){
      this.setState({number: this.state.number - 1})
   }
})
```

Comment: @AndrewL. nice, so basically use `setState`. I can close this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs

Answer (score -1):

If you do:

```
this.state = 1
```

it is a direct implementation but if you do it with the setter you can handle an exception or something like that befor you will initialize the value. In this case it doesn't matter.

I hope I could help you. :)

Comment: Wait, why are you setting `this.state`? Also, it *does matter*.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Where do I set this.state?

Comment: What does `this.state = 1` do? Why are you mutating *state*? You have to set a *property*

Comment: Oh i havn't seen it correct i'm sorry.