# Whats the difference b/w this.setState({name: 'xyz'}) vs normal value assignment( this.state.name='zyx')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whats the difference between `this.setState({name: 'xyz'})` vs Normal value assignment `this.state.name='zyx'`

```
// SetStateReact way of setting
tick = () => {
    this.setState({
        date: new Date()
    });
}

// Normal assignment
tick = () => {
    this.state.date= new Date();
}
```

Comment: The question should already be answered here ► [What the difference of this.state and this.setstate in ReactJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs)

Comment: Yes that answers what i wanted . Thanks @Fran