# Props of a child component are not coupled with state of parent

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have a parent component (App) that holds the `state`. Inside this component I have some code that manipulates the state through event handlers. So far so good.

However, I need to display the current `state` inside a child component (ChildComponent). I tried to achieve this by passing the state as a property to the ChildComponent, however I lose the dynamic coupling to the state. Any change to state is not reflected in the child component.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        // This should get dynamically updated
        return <div>{this.props.value.toString()}</div>
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 1};
    }

    // Do stuff here that changes state

    render() {
         return <ChildComponent value={this.state.value} />
    }
}
```

[works now: Updated correct example on codepen](http://codepen.io/snirp/pen/vxYjWG)

This example is a basic representation of my problem. I think I followed the example of the official docs, and specifically [lifting state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Somehow it does not work though. Could be me misinterpreting the docs (those also happen to be not so good).

edit: maybe having to do with the child component being a class rather than a function?

Comment: How do you update `state`? It should work, check this example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmOzXg

Comment: Do you use `setState`? `this.setState({value: 2});` or `this.state.value = 2`?

Comment: The second option. So I need to use the setState method to propagate the state changes to other components? Because it sure works without for just the state on the active component.

Comment: If you want to call `render()` function you should use `setState`.

Comment: I updated the codepen and it works. Could you post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it? For reasons of posterity and karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setState`. `setState` always triggers a re-render:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmOzXg

Comment: I learned it is also possible to manually trigger a re-render by calling `this.forceUpdate();`. Might be convenient if you only update a fraction of the state.

Comment: `Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate()`.

Comment: The reason I was doing that, is because it is a bit complicated to update nested objects within the `state`. I ended up avoiding nested objects in my state. IMO `setState` could really benefit from a function call like `setState('objectProperty.nestedProperty.nestedProperty', newValue)`

Answer (score 1):

You should not mutate the state of a component directly (`this.state.x = this.state.x + 1`), but use [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs) for additional info, and what the React docs *used* to say on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

This works as you expected:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        // This should get dynamically updated
        return <div>{this.props.value.toString()}</div>
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 1};
        this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    }

    addOne(event){
      this.setState({value: this.state.value+1})
      console.log(this.state.value)
    }

    // Do stuff here that changes state

    render() {
         return (
             <div>
                 <button onClick={this.addOne}>add 1</button>
                 <ChildComponent value={this.state.value} />
             </div>
         )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

You can test it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpwJPZ?editors=1111).

Comment: Seems to be identical to the updated CodePen I included with my question ;)

Comment: Of course, I get your code, improve it and now it works as expected. In your CodePin click on "Add 1" button does not change count. May be you shared  some non-final version.