# Is React's setState() guaranteed to create a new state object every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, does `setState` always assign a new object to `this.state`?
In other words, when you call:

```js
this.setState({
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2
});
```

does it always merge the current state object with the new properties into a new object, queueing an operation which is functionally equivalent to the following?

```js
this.state = {
   ...this.state,
   key1: val1,
   key2: val2
};
```

The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to know whether `this.state !== nextState` is **always** guaranteed to be true inside *shouldComponentUpdate()* if the update was triggered by `setState`.

Thanks.

Comment: this is duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs

Comment: you don't want to mutate this.state like in the second example, use this.setState always as advised in react docs

Comment: @eenagy I don't really see how it's a duplicate. I'm not asking about the difference between using `setState` and `this.state = ...`. I never assign to the state object directly myself; I'm asking about the internal implementation of `setState`, and whether it returns a new object which doesn't have reference equality to the previous state object.

Comment: you are right, it's not duplicate, mistake on my part about that

Comment: No worries. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer to your question will be **"Yes"**, but for one update cycle. Let me explain this.

As you may already know React `setState` does not always immediately update the component. Sometimes React batch or defer the updates until later. As an example, let's assume you have something like follows in your event handler.

```
onClick() {
  this.setState({quantity: state.quantity + 1});
  this.setState({quantity: state.quantity + 1});
  this.setState({quantity: state.quantity + 1});
}
```

These state update will be queued and execute all together in one update cycle. In such scenario React only create a new state object for the first `setState` and that object will mutate for subsequent `setState` updates. You can clearly see this in the source code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8b1b0720cc856d6b43d35dd29e50f260c7472347/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L984-L999).

However, this is something totally about how React works under the hood and we won't need to worry about that. Because there will be only one `shouldComponentUpdate()` and `componentDidUpdate()` for one cycle. By the time we access the `state` it will be always a new object. So we can safely assume that setState() guaranteed to create a new state object every time. But make sure that you aware of other implications of `setState` which explains in [the official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

> I'd like to know whether `this.state !== nextState` is always guaranteed
>   to be true inside `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

The answer to your this question will be **"No"** as also explained in other answers. `shouldComponentUpdate()` will be called because of either state change, props change or both. So `this.state !== nextState` won't true if the component has updated only because of props change.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the question to make it clear that I meant to ask "is it guaranteed to be true if the update was triggered by `setState`". My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to know the answer to this question.

> Will this.state !== nextState is always guaranteed to be true inside
>   shouldComponentUpdate() ?

According to react docs `shouldComponentUpdate` will be called on three instance

- state changed
- props changed
- state and props changed

So if only props are changing, your current state will be equal the last unmodified state.

> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when `new props` or `state` are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

The first question that you asked are depends on your style of data management for your state.

> React lets you use whatever style of data management you want, including mutation.

And the docs also states that

> shallow merge of stateChange into the new state, e.g., to adjust a shopping cart item quantity

But looking at the internal parts of [setState](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f9af9aacd3c14288cd5869ff23cc71cdfb54d447/src/renderers/shared/fiber/ReactFiberUpdateQueue.js) `beginUpdateQueue` method let me doubtful when state gets mutated.

I think it would be wise to use immutability-helper for this part of the code, if you must guarantee that no mutation happens to the data.

Comment: Oops, I meant to ask if `nextState` will be a new object when `setState` is what triggered the update. Edited the question to reflect that. Thanks!