# is it ok to push to the array where array is in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have       subjectChecks : [] as state .I fear that this method of changing state my go wrong .Is it ok to change state this way by pushing?

```
handleSubjectChange = (termID,subjectID) => event => {
          if(event.target.checked){
              this.state.subjectChecks.push({termID,subjectID});
          } else {
              this.state.subjectChecks.pop({termID,subjectID});
          }
          //this.setState({ [termID]: event.target.checked });
      };
```

Comment: No you should not. And when accessing something in the previous state, use setState with a callback in which gets you access to the prevState

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this method of changing an array stored in state is wrong. You should make a copy of the original array, modify the copy and set it with setState:

```
let arr = this.state.subjectChecks.slice() //copy array
// modify arr as necessary
this.setState({subjectChecks: arr})
```

Comment: this is a good approach to doing what u asked for, `slice()` to copy the original array, and then `setState()` to replace the old with the new one.

Comment: Hey is this correct if i am trying to remove .else { 
        let clonedarr=this.state.subjectChecks.pop();
        this.setState({
            subjectChecks:clonedarr
        })

Answer (score 1):

Use assign instead

```
this.setState({
    subjectChecks: [...this.state.subjectChecks, {termID,subjectID}]
});
```

Comment: If accessing prev state, you should use the callback in setState which gives you access to the prevState

Answer (score 0):

React (and redux) are built on the principle of state immutability. You should always use [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update your state, otherwise react will not detect state changes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868086/2477619) answer.

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state