# Is the React State really immutable?

Tags: reactjs, state, immutability

I am developing a React App and stumbled upon this behavior of the React state which i am not really sure if it's correct!?

I initiate my State like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
someRequest()
   .then(...) //do stuff to get the Payload of the Response
   .then(response => {
      this.setState({
         obj1: response,
         obj2: response.someArr
      })
    })
}
```

And i have a formHandler that changes the state of obj2

```
formHandler = event => {
   ...
   this.setState({obj2: newArrState})
}
```

I always assumed that the React state is immutable so that obj2 hold a new reference to a new object/array after the `setState()` call.

However if i take a look at `this.state.obj1` i also see the changes propagated to `this.state.obj1.someArr` so that `this.state.obj1.someArr === this.state.obj2`

Is that a correct behavior?

Comment: Immutability is not a feature. Its a pattern you have to follow, in my understanding.

Comment: What's newArrState? How do you observe this? That's what matters here.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs

Comment: @etus
newArrState is a modified version of this.state.obj2 (the Array contains a more or less complex object thus there is no es6 spread magic thingy)

Nonetheless in my understanding setState creates a copy and therefore the reference from `obj1.someArr` shouldn't be affected. Am i wrong?

Comment: EDIT:
Clarification
`let newArrState = this.state.obj2;`


`newArrState.push(newObj);`


`this.setState({obj2: newArrState});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React` does not enforce immutability on your state. In fact, you can (but you [**absolutely should not**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)) modify it directly.
It is up to you, the developer to enforce immutability on your data, either using data structures that simply cannot be modified (e.g. [imuutable.js](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js)), or otherwise.

Comment: Yeah i allways thought they enforce it by creating a deep copy each time you call `setState()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a correct behaviour. React state should be maintained as if it is immutable as any value that is changed will be overriden by the next setState call.

From the React docs:

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state