# Assign an object to another object without all fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an object like this

```
this.currentRegion = {
    latitude: 25.3170013,
    longitude: 55.4748285,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
};
```

and another object

```
coords = {
    accuracy: 20,
    altitude: 5,
    heading: 0,
    latitude: 25.380599999999998,
    longitude: 55.3992,
    speed: 0,
}
```

I need

```
this.currentRegion = {
    latitude: 25.380599999999998,
    longitude: 55.3992,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
}
```

I tried `this.currentRegion = Object.assign(this.currentRegion, region.coords);` and got the error

> Attempting to set key on an object that is immutable and has been frozen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.currentRegion = {...this.currentRegion, latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.currentRegion.latitude = coords.latitude
this.currentRegion.longitude = coords.longitude
this.currentRegion.latitudeDelta = coords.latitudeDelta
this.currentRegion.longitudeDelta = coords.longitudeDelta
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying that in React use `this.setState({currentRegion : ...this.currentRegion, latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude })`

why use setState instead of this.state

> NEVER mutate **this.state** directly, as calling **setState()** afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat **this.state** as if it were
>   immutable.
>
> **setState()** does not immediately mutate **this.state** but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing **this.state** after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

For further discussion check here : [What the difference of this.state and this.setstate in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs)

Answer (score -1):

As with so many problems, you can solve this using `Array.prototype.reduce`.
The benefit of this solution is that you don't have to hardcode which fields you want to transfer — it will simply overwrite any fields that already exist.

```js
let currentRegion = {
  latitude: 25.3170013,
  longitude: 55.4748285,
  latitudeDelta: 123,
  longitudeDelta: 456,
};

const coords = {
  accuracy: 20,
  altitude: 5,
  heading: 0,
  latitude: 25.380599999999998,
  longitude: 55.3992,
  speed: 0,
};

console.log(currentRegion);

currentRegion = Object.keys(coords).reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (typeof acc[val] !== 'undefined') {
    acc[val] = coords[val];
  }

  return acc;
}, currentRegion);

console.log(currentRegion);
```